# Android 8.1.0 API 27: how to register to receive broadcasts about your app's Notification Settings Changes?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

Can anyone suggest an Action (intent) which an Android 8.1.0 system should broadcast to registered receivers when changing Notification Channel setting values?  Some years back, we did the work to update our notifications system into the required channels and groups and specified a broadcast receiver for the settings changes in the manifest (later on we had to fix that when they took away implicit intents, so now it registers in code too - but that's fixed already).  Our receiver sets internal "display" settings which correspond to the notification-channel setting chosen by the user into our sharedpreferences file.  That's what controls the display of the content when a user actually opens the app.

I have notes that say we tested this on Android 8, but the actions/intents we registered for don't exist until API28.  I'm unclear on how this ever passed on the 8.1 devices, but maybe we were focused on the notifications only and didn't notice the display.  So right now, we're stuck with notification settings changes working, but if a user happens to go to the app for something else, they still see messages they expected to be hidden.

Android 9+ notification settings changes work fine all the way through because the broadcast receiver registers for the new-in-API-28 `NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED`, `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_GROUP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED` and `ACTION_APP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED` and these get delivered fine when a user changes settings, since I can see the receiver runs and sets the preferences as we want.

Just to debug this, I registered our BroadcastListener for a few extra intents (basically everything that looked like it might have something to do with notifications!) - like this:

```
        // Register to receive a broadcast whenever notification settings are changed (before API 26 this was done by specifying in AndroidManifest only,):
        notificationSettingsReceiver = new NotificationSettingsBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(NotificationManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(NotificationManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(NotificationManager.ACTION_INTERRUPTION_FILTER_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(NotificationManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_GROUP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(NotificationManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(NotificationManager.ACTION_APP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(notificationSettingsReceiver,filter);
```

This proved that the code in my BroadcastReceiver is working fine in 8.1.0 if it would only get called; I can force it to run by changing a few Notification settings (disabling them, or changing the sounds, etc) and then switching the phone into do-not-disturb mode.  The actual notification-settings-changes don't ever cause any intent to arrive at my receiver, but the DND change *does*, so this triggers the notification settings to get written into sharedpreferences (which is where our display code is expecting to find them).

Pre-android 8 notification settings still seem to work fine too and we write these changes into our sharedpreferences file directly.  Something about compatibility must just handle this for us because it all still "just works" on API 23 devices.

If anyone could suggest a way for an API 27 device to listen for notification-channel settings changes, I would be most grateful!  There *has* to be a way to to this in API 27, isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of looking around and trying things, I was unable to have the NotificationManager in API 27 send anything at all to our BroadcastReceiver.

I *was* able to come up with a solution, although at first it seemed a bit heavy-handed.

For Android O+ devices, I simply added the same "syncPreferences" block of code to our app's onCreate, onResume and onDestroy methods which calls the same function as our BroadcastReceiver (which works fine in API 28+) to write the values into our shared_prefs file at that time. I say "heavy-handed" since it does it every time, regardless of whether anything has changed, but it actually works very well.  It's actually simpler than all the overhead of building a receiver and listening for notification changes... I could probably eliminate that whole process now!

As an amusing aside, as a trekker, I have to admit that I got quite a chuckle from whoever adds the android VERSION_CODES constants though!  Check the comment I found while looking up API numbers-to-buildcode declarations:

```
        /**
         * Q.
         * <p>
         * <em>Why? Why, to give you a taste of your future, a preview of things
         * to come. Con permiso, Capitan. The hall is rented, the orchestra
         * engaged. It's now time to see if you can dance.</em>
         */
        public static final int Q = 29;
```